# This particular code is not reading the input given as string 's'. How to correct this?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, stdout, stdin

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }

}
```

Comment: add `scan.nextLine();` after `scan.nextDouble();`

Comment: what is your error / output?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
 int i = scan.nextInt();
 scan.nextLine();
 double d = scan.nextDouble();
 scan.nextLine();
 String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Note that, `Scanner.nextInt()`, `Scanner.nextDouble` etc doesn't get the last next line. So you need to call them separately.